# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'corpus.txt'

Tags: python, file

Somewhy my code doesn't see file in the same directory when i try to read it

```
def write_doc(text):
       file = open('corpus.txt')
       Temp = file.read()
       file.write(Temp + '\n\n' + text)
       file.close()
```

I've tried to add r prefix, tried to include directory straight to the file, but it won't help

Comment: You'll need to add your directory layout to the question. Note that your scripts CWD may be different from where your script is.

Comment: Try to `import os` module then `print(os.getcwd())`. Is it the right directory?

Comment: As a side-note: You probably want to open that file in `a`ppend mode, and then just add `text` at the end of the file, instead of reading the entire file into memory just to write it back to disk...

Comment: A fix might be finding the absolute path, if the file really is in the same directory you should be able to use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'corpus.txt')` to dynamically get the absolute path. If that doesnt fix it, you can use `os.getcwd()` to get the working directory and debug it yourself (both of these code samples need the `os` import).